Sharepoint Webpart embed hubspot within iframe height not working
I have a problem with embedding a hubspot form in a sharepoint webpart using iframe. I can only see the full form if I set the height to 200% - which seems kinda silly in a sense. 
When I set it to 100% it cuts off the form 
So, when the window is resized on the 200%, the frame is not adjusting and because there is no scroll, we have missing buttons etc. It also seems that we cannot add script to embedded webparts. Anyone else out there have dealt with this?

i do not have hubspot to test this, but can you try this <iframe src="your-hubspot-form-url" style="width: 100%; height: 800px; overflow-y: scroll;"></iframe> 
